# Spaying my female dog and feeling guilty

Tags: dogs, surgery, neutering

I have my Indian female dog "Hazel" which I treat like my own daughter (though  I am a bachelor). I was reluctant to get her spayed as I felt like keeping her intact will be good.

But I need to go to my hometown for this Indian festival for 2 weeks and no one was ready to take a un-spayed dog in, so I got her spayed by a good vet but I cried during whole surgery duration.

It's been 2 days since her surgery and I am doing my best to keep her warm, safe and happy - but when I look at her I felt like I broke a fix dog. I feel guilty and still cry a most of the time.

Please tell me, there is something I can do for her to make her happy which makes me feel better? Could spaying have changed her behaviour in any ways? I want her to be my same old girl who plays wth me for hours, running, biting, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not feel guilty it's VERY good that you spayed her!! You've helped prevent so many bad things. At my work, although not very common to see intact females anymore, the ones we do see always have an issue!

The common issues I see with intact females are cancer and [pyometra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyometra) (essentially uterus fills with pus to the extent it kills your dog unless spayed), by spaying you significantly reduce the risk of cancer and completely eliminate the chance of a pyometra. You have unlocked the potential to give her a few more years of life :)

On a less serious note you also prevent the chances of her becoming pregnant which then you have possible c-sections and eclampsia (lack of calcium while nursing). They tend to not want to roam as much once spayed (roaming to search for a mate while in heat), you remove the chance of false pregnancy - where her body thinks she's pregnant and she goes through all the phases from nesting to lactating.

Comment: yes u r right ..  since she had her first heat cycle already 6 mnths back .. i experienced all those things and then she had false pregnancy which kind of scared me to death (because she literally stopped eating and her mammal glands were all swell up I thought it may be a symptoms of breast cancer in dog )